# Nativescript + Anguar2 intercept (touch/key)event

Tags: angular, nativescript, touch-event

I`m developing application with Nativescript+Angular2.

I want to intercept touch event in my page(activity),
 like did `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent` in Android.

It can be done by using `mainContainer.nativeElement.on(GestureTypes.touch, function (args: TouchGestureEventData)`, but there`s problem - top layout container cannot receive all touch event.(eg. listView is nested).

So I thought it was much better to intercept touch event before send it to child views.

Is there any way to do it?